# Javascript Remoting in Salesforce 1 ( may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe)

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, javascript-remoting

While attempting to use our currently existing visualforce pages in Salesforce 1,  we're greeted with an error message that says:
"Javascript proxies were not generated for controller : may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe."

I have found one solution that says to make all of our remote actions global but since we are working with a managed package that would also mean making changes to those remote actions down the line could really be an issue, and it would allow access to functionality that I would rather not expose. Is there something along the way that we may have missed, or is this truly the only way? At the moment I am considering writing an API of sorts to add a layer between our proprietary functionality.. but that also seems messy.

Thanks

Comment: This would be a regression in functionality and not intended. If you file a bug it would get fixed.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: yeah we've currently escalated the issue with our AE but no concrete response yet. I will update the question if/when we get one..

Comment: answered my own quesiton - had to do with window.location.. see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm for more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with how we were doing redirection on our landing page. We were using window.location to handle a custom redirect (dynamic page names), and this was causing salesforce1 to behave oddly. Since the rest of our application used Page refs to handle redirection there were no issues but once the app was iframed it was left in that state. Funny enough this is in the salesforce 1 documentation..

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm

But it was not something we had considered up until this point.